# Sort order table.getRows

Tags: sorting, google-bigquery

In the following simple example 'foo.csv' is a simple 3 column table. 
The first column is the line number. The second and third columns are strings.

I create the table using schema auto-detection.
(I've also tried creating a table with a specific schema with similar results.)
I then query it using table.getRows.
The rows returned are not in the order they were inserted. 
It took me a while to figure out the order, since it's neither order of insertion nor numerically by the first column.

The sort order is
 - Length of second column
 - Alphabetically by second column
 - Length of third column
 - Alphabetically by third column

which is completely useless as far as I'm concerned.
How can I either A) preserve the insertion order or B) sort by the first column?
This seems like a relatively straightforward request but I can't find any documentation on it.

```
const gcloud = require('google-cloud');
const storage = gcloud.storage();
const bigquery = gcloud.bigquery({ projectId: projectId });
const async = require('async');

const bucket = storage.bucket(storage.bucket);
const file = bucket.file('foo.csv');

const dataset = bigquery.dataset('dataset1');
const table = dataset.table('table1');

async.waterfall([
    (callback) => {
            table.import(file, {
                    autodetect: true,
                    maxBadRecords: 500000,
                    writeDisposition: 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
            }, callback);
    },
    (job, apiResponse, callback) => {
            async.retry({
                    times: 20000,
                    interval: 2000
            }, (retryCallback, results) => {
                    job.getMetadata((err, metadata) => {
                        let status = metadata.status.state;
                        retryCallback((status == 'DONE') ? null : status);
                    });
            }, callback);
    },
    (callback) => {
            table.getRows({
                    autoPaginate: false,
                    maxResults: 100
            }, callback);
    },
    (rows, nextQuery, info, callback) => {
            rows.forEach((row) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
            });
            callback(null);
    }
], (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `table.getRows` you can use `table.query` to pass an SQL query in which you could specify the sort using an `Order By` clause.

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/bigquery/0.3.0/bigquery/table?method=query

Comment: That works, and it solves my immediate problem. But is there a way to preserve the order of insertion, to cover the case where I don't have a column that I can sort on?

Comment: I don't know of any way, behind the scenes BigQuery works with columns and organises the data to make querying efficient. You could add an insertion time column, but you'd probably have to manually parse the csv file and add this information.